# regex doesnt allow spaces

Tags: php, regex

This bit of regex helps me validate IBAN numbers but it doesnt allow spaces. Some people add spaces to their IBAN numbers, which messes with the validation.

How can i make it so that it allows spaces anywhere the string?

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1,30}$/', $iban)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Why not first remove the spaces, then validate?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is `preg_match('/^[A-Z ]{2}[0-9 ]{2}[A-Z0-9 ]{1,30}$/', $iban)` - insert a space in each character class `[]`. But maybe you should check the question @SilentMonk linked.

Comment: @ClasG this is not correct

Comment: @ClasG: Your regex matches `A   A`

Comment: @devnull69 "How can i make it so that it allows spaces anywhere the string?" - i.m.o. my sugggestion is the *simple answer* to that question.

Comment: @Toto See my previous comment.

Comment: The OP certainly meant *additional* spaces, your regex matches spaces in place of characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1,30}$/', str_replace(' ', '', $iban))) {
  // do something
}
```